# Joint Density function - Transformation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, transformation

I came across the following stats problem online and I was wondering if my approach in solving this problem is correct. Could you kindly offer me any guidance?

**Problem statement**.

Assume that $X_1$ $\sim$ N(4, 9), $X_2$ $\sim$ B(16, 0.25), $X_3$ $\sim$ $\chi^2$(6) and $X_4$ has a beta distribution with $\alpha$ = 4 and $\beta$ = 6. The random variables $X_1$,
$X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent. Furthermore we see that Cov($X_1$,$X_4$) = 0.4,
Cov($X_2$,$X_4$) = −0.2 and Cov(X3,X4) = 0.15.

- Give the distribution of the following random variable:

$$W=\left(\frac{X_1-4}{3}\right)^2\;+X_3$$

**Current Approach** (to verify if correct).

1. Find the join probability of $X_1$ and $X_3$

Given that $X_1$ $\perp$ $X_3$, their joint probability function is given by:
$f_{X_1,X_3}(X_1,X_3)=f_{X_1}(X_1)f_{X_3}(X_3)$.

2. Transform to variable $W$

If we want to substitute to $X_1$, we will transform to $W$
$$
X_1=3\sqrt{W-X_3}+4
$$

$$
f_W(W)=\int f_{X_1}(X_1)f_{X_3}(X_3)\;dX_3
$$

$$
f_W(W)=\int^W_0 f_{X_1}(3\sqrt{W-X_3}+4)f_{X_3}(X_3)\;dX_3
$$

The distributions are given by:

$$
f_{X_3}(X_3)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\frac{v}{2})2^{v/2}}x_3^{v/2-1}e^{-x_3/2}
$$

$$
f_{X_1}(3\sqrt{W-X_3}+4)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(3\sqrt{W-X_3}+4-\mu)^2 /2\sigma^2}
$$

The $f_W(W)$ is proportional to the following integral (short way to not write the constants before the integral as it takes a bit of space):

$$
f_W(W)\propto \int^W_0 x_3^{v/2-1}e^{-x_3/2} e^{-(3\sqrt{W-X_3}+4-\mu)^2 /2\sigma^2}dx_3
$$

Then, I think I need to simplify the integral by plugging $\mu$, and $v$,

$$
f_W(W)\propto e^{-(w+25)/18}\int^W_0 e^{-(8x_3-30\sqrt{w-x_3})}x_3^5 dx_3
$$

After here, I am lost: I think I need to integrate this until I reach the form of a standard normal distribution that integrates to 1 or $\Gamma(x)$ function but I am not sure. Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

mmm the easiest way to obtain the requested distribution is by recognizing things and applying a moment generating function. How you are doing it turns out to be very hard and tedious. Note that $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent. And
$$
Z = \frac{X_1-4}{3} \sim N(0,1)
$$
and
$$
Z^2 = \left( \frac{X_1-4}{3} \right)^2 \sim \chi_{(1)}^{2}
$$
and we have
$$
W = Z^2 + X_3
$$
the sum of two $\chi_{(\cdot)}^2$ independent. Using moment generating function we have
\begin{align*}
M_{W}(w) & = M_{Z^2}(w)M_{X_3}(w) \\
&  = \frac{1}{(1-2w)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{(1-2w)^{6/2}} \\
& = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^{7/2}}
\end{align*}
then we have
$$
W \sim \chi_{(7)}^{2}
$$